# xml schema complextype

Tags: xml, schema, complextype

I'm trying to write a Schema for a xml similar to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<store>
    <book>title1</book>
    <poster>some text</poster>
    <poster>some text</poster>
    <book>title1</book>
    <poster>some text</poster>
</store>
```

I'd like to know if there is a complexType in Schema that allows the "book" and "poster" tags to appear a minumum of 0 times and an unlimited maximum number of times.  I need them to be able to appear in a casual order like: book, poster, book poster, poster.

I though I could simply not put a sequence, and write a schema like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="store" type="TStore"/>

    <xs:complexType name="TStore">
        <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="poster" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But this just isn't valid schema. The "xs:all" would be good if the book and poster tags appeared in a casual order, but only once. How can I fix it?
EDIT: a xs:choice with maxOccurs="unbounded" does the trick nicely.

I also don't understand why a simple repetition like this should require a sequence.
I consulted some tutorial, but I can't find a reference for this simple case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<tags>
    <tag>text1</tag>
    <tag>text2</tag>
    <tag>text3</tag>
</tags>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="tags" type="complexType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tag" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: It would help if you only asked one question at a time. You seem to have answered the first question yourself. In the second case, it's not clear what your question is. However, xs:sequence cannot be a child of xs:element - there needs to be an xs:complexType in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also don't understand why a simple repetition like this should require a sequence

Is this your actual question? The simple answer is that the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type) requires it.

The more detailed answer is that the validator wants an unambiguous specification of what it should look for. The `<xs:sequence>` unambiguously tells the validator that its contents represent an expected sequence of elements in the instance document. Just like `<xs:choice>` tells the validator that it should see only one of the contained elements.